# Creating cross-tabulation table from panda data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new to cross tables. I have 3 data frames (df_1,df_2,df_3) created in my Jupyther NoteBook:

df_1

```
person ID, date, price, location, code  

542, 12/04/12, $2.5, 66234, 103
```

df_2

```
Brand, region, location  

AA, Texas, 66234  

BB, SF, 15467
```

df_3

```
person ID, First, Last, Region  

542, Tom, Barker, Texas
```

I need to combine these data frames to get something like this:

```
Brand, code, Texas, SF  

AA, 103, $2.5, $3.8
```

Any idea where should I start?

Comment: You should explain a logic and post a code that you have tried. Please take a tour on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?